# Even changing the base color the cube is still black

Tags: rendering, modifiers, objects, texture-painting

I'm a beginner in the Blender program, I'm just doing my first practice and when I wanted to pass the cube to rendering (viewport shading). I realized that an error occurred. I have my normal object when I'm in solid mode, but when I try to go to the visual viewport it turns completely black and I can't change the base color of the object. I've been trying to solve this problem for weeks and I'm not succeeding. I don't know how to resolve this.

[image: Example of object still black]

Comment: Please edit your post with screenshots and/or your blend file https://blend-exchange.com/. We won't be able to help your otherwise.

Comment: Hello, maybe this is Z-Fighting (faces overlapping), try to switch to Edit mode and press M > Merge by Distance, or see if 2 donut objects are not overlapping? Or as Lutzi says, share your file

Comment: I delete the donout and start again, but doesn't change, the cube is still black

Comment: Please someone help me  i don't wanna give up. I've been trying to solve this problem for weeks, but I can't, I don't want to give up on Blender. 

Comment: Is what you show your default scene? If so, there must be a bug due to your graphic card, maybe switch to a previous driver?

Comment: Maybe your *Material Preview* is faulty, do you also get the black color when rendering ?

Comment: I tried to color the cube but it didn't work, the cube remains black, even the base color no matter how much I change the color it remains black, no matter how much I delete the material the color remains black.

Comment: I'd guess that's a graphics driver problem not a Blender problem. Try updating your machine's graphics driver. If that doesn't do it we'll need to see your Blend file as @Lutzi says. You can share it via https://blend-exchange.com/ following the instructions there to copy the link on that page. Then [edit](https://blender.stackexchange.com/posts/314385/edit) your question here and paste the link into it.

Answer (score 0):

Your Base Color in the Shader is overwritten by the Texture Layer Image that is fed into it - so you can tell it to change to red or green or whatever and it will still display the black that is in the image texture. Switch to texture paint mode and try painting on it with a color in the brush tool settings and see if you get a color change then. Look at your Shader editor to see if you have an image texture fed into the main Principled Shader. If so, then you can paint and change your color.